# How to get id of element of selector class in jquery on()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am well aware that I can get the id of an element like this:

```
$('.class').on('click', () => {
  console.log(this.id);
  //this gets the id
});

$('.class').on('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  //this gets the id as well
});
```

The problem that I have here is that the javascript fuctions doesn't work on my DOM, as I injected the HTML with javascript with `$('someDiv).append("<div id='someId'></div>")`

So the only way (at least to my knowledge) to get it working is to do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.id);
  //and this prints undefined
});
```

I get `undefined` as `this` is referring to the `document` not the actually div that I was clicking on.

Edit: I see that there is difference between `function()` and `()=>{}` I have tried this as well:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  //and I still get a blank output
});
```

I can't call the `$('.class').on('click')` directly as the HTML is injected with javascript as mentioned above. So I am forced to use the `'.class'` as a selector in the `$(document).on('click')` function like so. The problem is the event fired is showing that `document` is the target but not the selector so I will only get the document when I do `event.target`, thus getting nothing from `event.target.id`.

Edit 2:
using the event doesn't work but `this` returns the element that I am clicking on so I can get its id with `this.id`

Comment: You're using jQuery... you can just use `$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: Or you could try to use a regular `function` instead of an arrow function. The arrow function does not have its own context, which causes `this` to be bound to the outer scope.

Comment: @emsoff WRONG, that is not going to work with arrow function.

Comment: @epascarello THANKS. It was a comment meant to point them in a direction, not an answer. If OP's scope is not what is expected, remove the arrow functions and use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the differences between an arrow function (`() => {}`) and a regular `function` is that the regular `function` has its own context, and the arrow does not. Instead, when using `this` in the arrow function, the arrow function will use the scope of its parent.

Consider the following example where we create one regular `function` and an arrow function, and try to bound it the context `{ name: 'Steve' }`

```
// Create context
const context = { name: 'Steve' };

const fn1 = function () {
  // Will print Steve, as this function will have its own context and is now bound to context we created.
  console.log(this.name)
}

const fn2 = () => {
  // This function does not have its own context, and will use the scope of the parent. In this case `window`. So, the function will log `window.name` instead.
  console.log(this.name)
}

fn1.call(context)
fn2.call(context)
```

To solve your problem, you can use the same principle. Use a regular function instead of an arrow function. Example:

Having the following html:

```
<div id="id_1" class="class_1">Div #1</div>
<div id="id_2" class="class_2">Div #2</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('.class_1').on('click', () => {
  // This will be in the window context and log undefined (window.id)
  console.log(this.id);
});

$('.class_2').on('click', function() {
  // This will be bound to the jQuery context and log the element's id
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

This should solve your problem. Live example here if you want to try for yourself https://jsbin.com/wojipuloti/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score -1):

```
I found it syntactically wrong, it should be, 
$('.class').on('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  //this gets the id as well
});
You forgot to close quotes in $('.class'). Also in $('someDiv).append("<div></div>") you need to close quotes and try after this.


$(document).on('click', '.class', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.id);
  //and this prints undefined
});
```

when click event occurs,click handler should print id of element which is clicked.As per your code,

```
$('someDiv).append("<div></div>")
```

you are not defining any id on the element. You can try after adding id on the element, it will work.

Comment: The quotations are a mistake and I do know that the id has to be specified I just didn't type it out. I am doing exactly as you mentioned and I get an empty output